# FtpWebRequest not working if not static?

Tags: c#, ftpwebrequest

I have been working on a project that requires me to upload to and download from an FTP server. I had the whole system working, but the code was ugly to say the least and since a decent chunk of the program was static (please don't shoot me!), it was very hard to develop.

I have recently decided to rewrite a good chunk of the program, but I did not change anything in the specific code for the FTP Upload, except for moving this from a static function to a non-static function. Still it somehow doesn't seem to work and the error I'm getting gives me no useful information. Could it be that this can only be executed in this way if the function is static?

```
FtpWebRequest ftpRequest;
FtpWebResponse ftpResponse;
StreamReader fileReader;

try
{
    ftpRequest = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
    ftpRequest.Timeout = 50000;
    ftpRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
    ftpRequest.KeepAlive = false;
    ftpRequest.UseBinary = false;
    ftpRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);

    //creating payload;
    fileReader = new StreamReader(SystemStrings.file_Location + SystemStrings.file_Name);
    byte[] file = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(fileReader.ReadToEnd());
    fileReader.Close();
    ftpRequest.ContentLength = file.Length;

    //using the payload
    Stream stream = ftpRequest.GetRequestStream();     <---- Throws WebException here
    stream.Write(file, 0, file.Length);
    stream.Close();

    //handling the response;
    ftpResponse = (FtpWebResponse)ftpRequest.GetResponse();
    ftpResponse.Close();

    //If we haven't gotten an exception at this point, everything succeeded, so let's return the details
    cred.Username = username;
    cred.Password = password;
    return true;
}
catch (WebException we)
{
        ...
}
catch (Exception e)
{
        ...
}
```

The error I'm getting is caught by WebException but doesn't explain anything, and the only error I can find at the point where it throws the WebException is that ContentType throws a NotSupportedException, but according to MSDN it should always do that?

Some extra information:

- cred is a custom credentials object that has a Username and a Password amongst other things
- the timeout is set to 50000 to make sure that timeout wasn't the problem
- the username and password are correct and the server is up, this is all verified

Any suggestions?

-Peter

Comment: Have you tried putting the method back to static? Does it start working then? Does the file you are uploading definitely exist?

Comment: The quick answers to your questions are No (haven't tried), Don't know (if it works) and Yes(the file definitely exists). Changing it back to static would make a mess of the program, so I would like to try other options before I apply such radical changes :)

Comment: If you are using source control (it's a good idea to even on small personal projects), you can do a diff between the last version of the file and what you have now - you might be able to spot any changes you had forgotten/not seen etc.

Comment: I have the old version still here, and the code is literally identical except for the timeout (made it longer, but even with the same timeout it doesn't work) and the fact that the code is not in a static function anymore. Could there be a race condition by any chance?